# the input type="range" moves abruptly when I add it in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable with 3 values `$scope.values`. and for every value I'm creating a slider. basically the maximum value of each slider is the value of `item.value`, the minimum will always be 2 and the current value will be the highest. but I do not know why I'm getting this weird behavior. you can not move the slider fluently.

how can I solve that? thank you very much

http://jsfiddle.net/2ot0n840/

```
<div ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in values">
    <input type='range' ng-model="item.value" max="{{item.value}}" min="2" value="{{item.value}}">
    <span>{{item.value}}</span>
  </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CalcCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.values=
  [
    { "value":30},
    { "value":50},
    { "value":1}

   //current value= is item.value
   //max value is item.value
   //min value is 2.

  ]
```

Comment: your `max` and `value` are bounded to `item.value`, so if you change the value, it changes the max and makes it equal to it. You can only decrement it. So add another variable `$scope.max = 90;` and change `max={{max}}`

Comment: @yavg, `Aleksey` comment and my answers are working for your problem. please give a response for mark as answer/upvote

Comment: @AlekseySolovey thanks, but I need if or if the maximum is equal to the item.value for each of the input range .. how can I solve it? I will not create a variable {{max}} for each one

Comment: @yavg they are bounded, you can't separate them. Consider making a copy with a new model - `$scope.max[i] = angular.copy($scope.items[i].value)` for each _range_ in a loop

Comment: @yavg See 1+1=2 We can't change it right? As same as if max value and actual value is same then the result should be 100%, which is you are getting now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're using the same max value as your actual value so every time you adjust it the max value changes. You can see this by inspecting the dom. Instead you should have something like this:

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in values">
    <input type='range' ng-model="item.value" max="{{item.max}}" min="2">
    <span>{{item.value}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CalcCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.values=
  [
    { "value":30, "max": 30},
    { "value":50, "max": 50},
    { "value":1, "max": 1}

   //current value= is item.value
   //max value is item.value
   //min value is 2.

  ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ng-model` value and `max` value is shouldn't be same. Because if the `max` value is 50 and the `ng-model` value is 50 then it should be show 100%.
Try this

```
<input type='range' ng-model="item.value" max="100" min="2" value="{{item.value}}">
```

### Demo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CalcCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.values=
  [    
    { "value":30},
    { "value":50},
    { "value":1}
   
   //current value= is item.value
   //max value is item.value
   //min value is 2.
    
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="CalcCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in values">
    <input type='range' ng-model="item.value" max="100" min="2" value="{{item.value}}">
    <span>{{item.value}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but I need if or if the maximum is equal to the item.value for each of the input range .. how can I solve it? I will not create a variable {{max}} for each one

Comment: @yavg **Strange!** Please think about the logic sense.  If max and actual value is same, then the result should be show full  range. You are asking to us like please make the world calculation to `1+1=4`. Just kidding